# Action script coding standards

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am very good java script developer, but newbie to flash. I have started learning action script. I am reading code snippets at many places. I found that variable names starting with m_Variable_Name or _Variable_name. What does that mean when it starts with m_ or _ ?  Can anyone throw a light on coding standard?

Sample code :

```
 public class Person implements IPerson
 {
  private var m_name:String;

  public function get name():String
  {
   return m_name;
  }

  public function set name(value:String):void
  {
   m_name = value;
  } 
 }
```

Comment: `_name` > anything else > `m_name` imo.

Comment: `m_name` came from C++, all AS3 developers I know hate when `m_` is used in AS3 classes. Ported C/C++ code looks so ugly in AS3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are [Adobe Coding Conventions](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Coding%20Conventions).

Some people use `m_` or `_` to prefix member variables to distinguish them from local variables.

Comment: Adobe changed url for above link, now it's located here - http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Coding%20Conventions If anyone comes here from Google (as I have), it may help them :)

Answer (score 3):

prefixes m_ is used as a prefix for member variables.

Answer (score 3):

Prefixing variable names is not a requirement, it's more of a naming convention that you might choose to use.